# selenium+python calls ie8 failed

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer-8

I have searched the whole internet but didnt get the answer and even a similar onoe, so i decide to post here.

Enviroment:
*windows7, python version 3.4, selenium version 3.7, IEDriverServer3.7.*

the problem description is simple, I failed at this command

```
browser=webdriver.Ie()
```

and for 100% sure, I ***have downloaded the IEDriverServer.exe*** and the ***variable PATH has been appropriately modified*** to link to IEDriverServer.exe. And I have tested this linking by calling firefox instead of ie8 with geckodriver.exe in the same path as IEDriverServer.exe's. Undoutedly, it worked smoothly.

the whole passage of code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
import socket

DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER['ignoreProtectedModeSettings']=True

browser=webdriver.Ie();#selenium just stucked here
```

and the error report is here(it ended with a piece of html code):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nnceb/PycharmProjects/seleniumer/seleniumer.py", line 10, in <module>
    browser=webdriver.Ie();
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 82, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 240, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 165, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
<style type="text/css"><!-- 
 body
{
        font-family: "Microsoft YaHei", "宋体", "Segoe UI", "verdana", "arial";
        background-image: url(http://www.netentsec.com/download/nps/squid_bg.jpg);
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-color: #E8EAEF;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        color: #575757;
}
a
{
        color: rgb(19,112,171); font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
        vertical-align: top;
}
a:link, a:visited
{
        color: rgb(19,112,171);
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align: top;
}
a:hover
{
        color: rgb(7,74,229);
        text-decoration: underline;
}
p
{
        font-size: 0.9em;
}    
h1 /* used for Title */
{
        color: #4465A2;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        font-weight: normal;
        vertical-align:bottom;
        margin-top: 7px;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
}
h2 /* used for Heading in Main Body */
{
        font-size: 0.9em;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin-top: 20px;       
        margin-bottom: 1px;
}
h3 /* used for text in main body */
{
        font-size: 0.9em;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin-top: 10px;       
        margin-bottom: 1px;
}
h4 /* used for task links*/
{
        font-size: 0.9em;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin-top: 12px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
}
h5 /* used for Heading in InfoBlock */
{
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-top: 1px;        
        font-size: 0.9em;
        color: #575757;
}
.actionIcon /* used for task link icons */
{
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 6px;
}
.infoBlock
{
        padding-left: 25px;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        display: block;
        line-height: 1.1 em;
        color: #575757;
}
.errorCodeAndDivider
{
        font-size: 0.7em;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #787878;
}
ul, ol
{
        font-size: 0.9em;
        list-style-position: outside;
        margin-top: 1px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
        line-height: 1.3em;
}
.myul li{ list-style-type:none;}
.myul li{ background:url(http://www.netentsec.com/download/nps/s.gif) no-repeat 4px 8px; line-height:2.5em; padding-left:30px; font-family:"Microsoft YaHei", "宋体"; font-size: 0.9em;}
.divider
{
        border-bottom: #B6BCC6 1px solid;
}


body
:lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-serif; float: right; }
:lang(he) { direction: rtl; }
 --></style>
</head><body id=ERR_CONNECT_FAIL>
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5555/session">http://127.0.0.1:5555/session</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Connection to 127.0.0.1 failed.</b></p>
</blockquote>

<p id="sysmsg">The system returned: <i>(111) Connection refused</i></p>

<p>The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.</p>

<p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:webmaster?subject=CacheErrorInfo%20-%20ERR_CONNECT_FAIL&amp;body=CacheHost%3A%20netentsec-nps-192.168.168.1%0D%0AErrPage%3A%20ERR_CONNECT_FAIL%0D%0AErr%3A%20(111)%20Connection%20refused%0D%0ATimeStamp%3A%20Fri,%2017%20Nov%202017%2009%3A37%3A17%20GMT%0D%0A%0D%0AClientIP%3A%2012.35.17.241%0D%0AServerIP%3A%20127.0.0.1%0D%0A%0D%0AHTTP%20Request%3A%0D%0APOST%20%2Fsession%20HTTP%2F1.1%0AAccept-Encoding%3A%20identity%0D%0AHost%3A%20127.0.0.1%3A5555%0D%0AAccept%3A%20application%2Fjson%0D%0AConnection%3A%20close%0D%0AContent-Type%3A%20application%2Fjson%3Bcharset%3DUTF-8%0D%0AContent-Length%3A%2084%0D%0AUser-Agent%3A%20Python%20http%20auth%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A">webmaster</a>.</p>

<br>
</div>

<hr>
<div id="footer">
<p>Generated Fri, 17 Nov 2017 09:37:17 GMT by netentsec-nps-192.168.168.1 (nps/2.3.1)</p>
<!-- ERR_CONNECT_FAIL -->
</div>
</body></html>
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I use Ie8 to render the html code above get this page as below：
[the html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtl52.png)

I have thought about this problem further, surposed it is because the port IEDriverServer uses as default is different to the one selenium uses for random. I open the IEDriverServer and everytime it shows it uses port 5555. 
[Open the IEDriverServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cci9g.png)

So I modifed the source code to use port 5555 by default instead of randomo. However it does not work, with the same error report returned.